# Snapshot testing using Karma Angular and not jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx, snapshot-testing

Apologies if the question sounds incomplete. I have learnt NgRx recently and realized that snapshot testing would make life easier compared to asserting in case of NgRx. However, i don't want to migrate from Karma to Jest (don't want to change the entire flow of the project for this one part). What is the best way to test NgRx using Karma, the way snapshot testing is done?. I saw a few packages in the npm, but is there anything first hand from karma?, Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-snapshot Seems to be your best option. I haven't used it personally, but it seems to do what you want.

Comment: Has anyone already tried this library? I am trying without success. And I can't find a better alternative.